# CakePHP Ajax delete

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to delete cakephp data by ajax.Here I have changed postlink button to simple html button like as

```
<button class="del" id=<?php echo $user['User']['id']; ?>>Delete </delete>
```

Here now I am able to get user id by bellow code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        $('.del').click(function(){
            var x=$(this).attr("id");
            alert(x);
        });
    });
```

I have successfully get id of the user.Now I am trying to sent it for userscontroller in delete action.So I have coded like

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        $('.del').click(function(){
            var x=$(this).attr("id");
            alert(x);
            jQuery.get("<?php echo $this->webroot . $this->params["users"]; ?>/delete",{"id":x},function(data,stat){
                                 jQuery("#success").load("success.ctp");
            });
        });
    });
```

Now in controller in delete action I have tried

```
public function delete($id=NUll) {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } 
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

Here it's not working.In controller how can I defined it ?

Comment: What YOUR BROWSER generates `jQuery.get("<?php echo $this->webroot . $this->params["users"]; ?>/delete",{"id":x},function(data,stat){
                                 jQuery("#success").load("success.ctp");
            });`  as HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the wrong was only url, I have changed it and now it's working fine

```
echo $this->webroot . $this->params["users"]; ?>/delete"
```

TO

```
echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'delete'));?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If u use before filter,

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    //Here set Which pages should be accessable to various users
    $adminPages =array('delete');
    $this->Auth->allow($adminPages);

    ...... 
}
```

Allow it to be executed using Auth allow.

If thats also working fine,Check if AJAX string is proper. Check using MANUAL DELETE like  `abc.com/Users/delete/id:2`  Just copy paste string u get in `jQuery.get()`. Does it delete properly??

**IF ALL DOESNT Work TRY following : :)**

```
public function delete($id=NUll) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been deleted.'));
    } 
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

And ajax :

```
        jQuery.get("<?php echo $this->webroot . $this->params["users"].'/delete/';?>"+x+"",{"id":x},function(data,stat){
                             jQuery("#success").load("success.ctp");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this if you want to use ajax**

```
   public function delete_user() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if ($this->request->data) {

        $this->User->id = $this->request->data['id'];
        $update = $this->User->saveField($this->request->data['field'], $this->request->data['value']);
        if ($update) {
            $repsonce['success'] = '1';
            $this->Session->setFlash(__d('User', 'User Deleted successfully'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
        } else {
            $repsonce['success'] = '0';
        }
    } else {

        $repsonce['success'] = '0';
    }
    echo json_encode($repsonce);
}
```